# Normal direction from rotation

Tags: python

I have two imported object that were alligned with the axes and then rotated. One was initially pointing upwards (0,0,1) and one forwards (0,-1,0). I now wonder how I can determine the new normal direction after rotation? I tried

```
v = mathutils.Vector((0,-1,0))
print (v.rotate(ob.rotation_euler))
```

but it did not work.
[image]

Comment: When you say that "it didn't work", do you mean that it does not give you the result you were expecting or does Blender raise an exception in the script you're running?

Comment: All I get is "None"

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `v.rotate(ob.rotation_euler)` modifies the state of the vector `v`, but does not return a value. Instead of using `print(v.rotate(ob.rotation_euler))` you can modify the rotation first and then inspect the value through `print(v)`.

```
import bpy
import mathutils

ob = bpy.context.object
v = mathutils.Vector((0,-1,0))
print(f"vector before: {v}")
v.rotate(ob.rotation_euler)
print(f"vector after: {v}")
```